# Convert form select box from .pug to .ejs

Tags: node.js, pug, ejs

I'm trying to convert the below from pug to ejs. It's a select box of authors (from an associated collection) in a form to add a book to the db. It throws error "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined" pointing to the first option element when I add a new book (but I can update an existing book for some reason). And in the pug version it doesn't throw this error. Is my conversion right?

```
select#author.form-control(type='select', placeholder='Select author' name='author' required='true' )
  - authors.sort(function(a, b) {let textA = a.family_name.toUpperCase(); let textB = b.family_name.toUpperCase(); return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;});
  for author in authors
    if book
      option(value=author._id selected=(author._id.toString()==book.author._id.toString() ? 'selected' : false) ) #{author.name}
    else
      option(value=author._id) #{author.name}
```

My conversion:

```
<select class="form-control" id="author" type="select" placeholder="Select author" name="author" required="true">
  <% authors.sort(function(a, b) {let textA = a.family_name.toUpperCase(); let textB = b.family_name.toUpperCase(); return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;}); %>
  <% authors.forEach(function(author) { %>
    <% if(typeof book !== 'undefined') { %>
      <option value="<%= author._id %>" selected=<%= (author._id.toString() == book.author._id.toString()) ? 'selected' : 'false' %>><%= author.name %></option>
    <% } else { %>
      <option value="<% author._id %>"><%= author.name %></option>
    <% } %>
  <% }) %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion is right. Just a little mistake here `<%=` instead of `<%`

```
<option value="<%= author._id %>"><%= author.name %></option>
```

For any reason `book.author` is not present. Pug is catching undefined variables and continues rendering while ejs doesn't. So there is something wrong in your data.

Modify this line to prevent the error `<% if(typeof book !== 'undefined' && 'author' in book) { %>`

```
<select class="form-control" id="author" type="select" placeholder="Select author" name="author" required="true">
  <% authors.sort(function(a, b) {let textA = a.family_name.toUpperCase(); let textB = b.family_name.toUpperCase(); return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;}); %>
  <% authors.forEach(function(author) { %>
    <% if(typeof book !== 'undefined' && 'author' in book) { %>
      <option value="<%= author._id %>" selected=<%= (author._id.toString() == book.author._id.toString()) ? 'selected' : 'false' %>><%= author.name %></option>
    <% } else { %>
      <option value="<%= author._id %>"><%= author.name %></option>
    <% } %>
  <% }) %>
</select>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I was thrown off because the error message was pointing to the first option element for some reason not the second where I forgot the = sign.